# Which Star Wars character is Vinnie a parody of?

Tags: character, spaceballs

Almost every character in [*Spaceballs* (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/) is based off someone from Star Wars, especially the ones with bigger roles.

- Princess Vespa is Princess Leia
- Dot Matrix is C-3PO
- Dark Helmet is Darth Vader
- Lone Starr is a mixture of Han and Luke

So who is Vinnie, Pizza the Hutt's associate, supposed to be? I can't think of anybody from the original trilogy that he resembles. His [wiki](http://spaceballs.wikia.com/wiki/Vinnie) says *Max Headroom* was a source of inspiration for his speech pattern, but I'm wanting to know what in-universe Star Wars character he's closest to.

[image]

Comment: Well, there are other characters that aren't related to in universe Star Wars characters such as President Skroob, Prince Valium and King Roland.  All of them actually had more screen time than Vinnie.  Also, not all of the characters are references to just Star Wars.  Several other movie/television characters are parodied such as Planet of the Apes, Star Trek and Alien just to name a few.

Comment: Just to add a couple more: Barf = Chewbacca, Colonel Sandurz = Grand Moff Tarkin (?)

Answer (score 7):

If I were *forced* (pun intended) to relate him to a Star Wars character, I'd actually have to go with [Bib Fortuna](http://www.starwars.com/databank/bib-fortuna), Jabba's Twi'lek "assistant". Obviously not because of his physical appearance, but Vinnie is somewhat sycophantic (his line, "You're delicious"); he's right there next to Pizza the Hut, just as Bib Fortuna seems to have his place in Jabba's palace right beside the Hutt; and also Vinnie gives me the impression that he's a bit "simple", similar to Bib Fortuna (Jabba's line about him being a "weak-minded fool").

Comment: First answer that came into my head too - If Pizza The Hut is a clear parody of Jabba then it is only logical that Vinnie represents Bibs' place within the court. 'De wanna wanga!'

Answer (score 2):

None.  There is no Jabba the Hutt accomplice that even remotely resembles him.  If anything, you might say he took the place of Boba Fett, as Boba was a bounty hunter.  But really, the character of Vinny didn't exist in the Star Wars galaxy.

Comment: I can kinda see Fett. The skin color and the sunglasses resemble his helmet.